# Defining a html class with a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, class

I'm developing a website and I'm having some trouple..
I want to define my class using a Javascript function, like so:

html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/active_menu.js"></script>
<a id="demo" class="<script>document.write(myFunction('index.php'));</script>" href="index.php">Home</a>
```

javascript code:

```
function myFunction(menu_punkt)
{
var state = 'not_active'
var a = document.URL.split("//");
a = (a[1] ? a[1] : a[0]).split("/"); 
a = a[1];

if (menu_punkt == a){
    state = 'navactive';
}
return state
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure... It should make the class="navactive" and then my menu button should be blue, but it doesn't happen. And it works if I just put in class="navactive"

Comment: Could you please explain what you're trying to achieve so we may better help? but from what I see it looks like you're trying to set the home link to a class based on whether or not you're on that current page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `<script>` tag inside an attribute. Probably the simplest change would be to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/active_menu.js"></script>
<script>document.write('<a id="demo" class="' + myFunction('index.php') + '" href="index.php">Home</a>');</script>
```

If you want your page to be more accessible to users with JavaScript disabled, or you want to allow the DOM to continue to load without blocking on JS execution, you might consider an approach that changes the element after the fact instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `className` property:

```
document.getElementById("demo").className = myFunction('index.php');
```

Make sure you call this *after* `demo` has been added to the DOM, else `document.getElementById("demo")` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the `<script>` tags from the 'class' value, you can make this much more elegant with JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').addClass(myFunction('index.php'))
});

function myFunction(menu_punkt)
{
    var state = 'not_active'
    var a = document.URL.split("//");
```

[http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$%28document%29.ready%28%29](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29)

*If you don't want to hardcode the name of your page in your function's argument, you can sort something out with 'window.location.href' and the 'substr' function.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp